# X-ray radiation - What does h * fmax = e * U mean?

Tags: energy, photons

I'm trying to figure out this formula for X-ray radiation

$$h \times f_{max} = e \times U$$

$h$ = Planck's constant

$f_{max}$ = maximum frequency, in hertz (?), that the photons can have because of ?

$e$ = elementary charge?

Example from the book says:

X-ray tube has voltage $U = 33$ kV (kilovolt)
The maximum frequency from the tube (what does that mean, anyway? What is the frequency in the tube? Why does it have a max?) becomes:

$$f_{max} = eU/h = (1.6 \times 10^{-19} \times 33 \times 10^3)/(6.63 \times 10^{-34}) \text{Hz} = 8.0 \times 10^{18}\text{Hz}$$

what is "$e$", $1.6 \times 10^{-19}$?
This "$33 \times 10^3$" is "$U$", (voltage)?

Comment: Did this come out of a textbook?  Who on Earth uses $U$ for voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$eU$ is the energy of a charge $e$ after it's accelerated by a potential difference (voltage) $U$. In this case, yes, $e$ is the elementary charge.

$hf$ is the energy of a photon (X-ray or otherwise) with frequency $f$. If we assume that all the energy of the accelerated charge gets converted into the energy of a photon, and here this will be the maximum energy that could be transferred, i.e. $E_{max}$, then the largest frequency of a photon that this corresponds to, $f_{max}$, will be given by the equation you have used.

Answer (score 0):

Photon is a (one) quantum of electromagnetic radiation/light, ok?

When it has low energy, means large wavelength, means low frequency, we know it as radio waves.

Some higher energy, means higher frequency, means lower wavelength, we see it as light.

At, even higher energy it is X-rays. Let us stop here. The formula for single photon's energy is $E=h\cdot \nu = h f = h /\lambda$, where frequency $\nu$ is the same as $f$ in your notation. Remember, it is only one photon energy.

Imagine, in the Xray tube, you accelerate **one** electron. The energy of the electron is proportional to its charge $e=1.6\times 10^{-19}$ and the tension (your $U = 33 kV$). Its energy is $E_e=e\cdot U$.

Now the trick: The accelerated electron crashes to a material of electrode and (in good cicumstances) converts **all** its energy $E_e$ to **one** photon. You see? Now $E_e = h f$, you know Planck constant, you get the frequency. No idea however, what the knowledge of frequency is good for.

Why *max*? Not all energy of electron has to be always converted to **one** single photon.